# What does 愛想薄い mean?

Tags: meaning, words

I came across this in a doujinshi I was reading; the context was two people were discussing another character and basically it lead to a question asking if one of them was fine with 愛想薄い, in terms of personality, in exchange for a nice body.

[I asked this on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/4qp8nt/translation_help_%E6%84%9B%E6%83%B3%E8%96%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B/) some time ago and I did receive an answer from a native speaker but I only got 3 answers so I figured I'd try asking on here to just make sure what they said was correct or if anyone else might have any other possible explanation.

Comment: 「愛想(が/の) **薄い** 」んですから、「(全く) 愛想が無い・愛想が悪い・無愛想な」というよりも、「愛想が**あまり**無い 」「愛想が**あまり・さほど**良くない 」という感じがするんですが・・・

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We say "人情が篤い, 薄い- warm / cold at heart" quite often, but I've never heard of the expression, "愛想薄い." It sounds awkward. If this expression is allowed, "愛想厚い" or "愛想濃い," both sound more awkward, should be accepted as an antonym to "愛想薄い."

When we describe the person who is surly, unfriendly, or blunt, we say (he or she is) "愛想が悪い, 愛想がない, or 不愛想な(人)."

We call an extremely blunt person "愛想も"へったくれも"ない人."

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find [one question](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13161759943) using it.  I'm guessing it's similar to [無愛想｛ぶあいそ｝](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%8D%E6%84%9B%E6%83%B3) the opposite of ["friendliness" or "sociability"](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%84%9B%E6%83%B3) or that their friendliness isn't very obvious as in 薄い{うすい} (light/faint).

See other uses of

存在感｛そんざいかん｝が薄い人 - someone that has no presence

Answer (score 2):

愛想薄い -- I was unfamiliar with it, but it's such a great word, I wonder why it's not more common.

愛想薄い is used when a person  is wooden, or robot-like, or unresponsive... --- and isn't so unfriendly (impolite) as to be described as: ​無愛想, 不愛想, 愛想が悪い, 愛想がない...

On the net, it's mostly used to describe shop-clerks (店員) and dogs.

- (店員) コンビニバイト -- 表情硬い人・愛想薄い人も合格できますか？
- (talking about a dog (?)) うちのシヴァも家族には愛想薄いくせに他人はえらい熱烈歓迎してたな…